# Azure pipeline Error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'atlstr.h' since yesterday

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Ok first of all, this is probably on Azure Pipelines side and some change that happened on Wednesday on their server-side (we do not use our own servers, all runs on Azure machines). Do not redirect me to how to reference ALT libraries in Visual Studio for a C++ project because our project does build locally perfectly. Even more, I have triggered the same pipeline, on the same exact commit on Wednesday and Today, and one is completely successful, and the pipeline build today fails with:

> Error MSB8041: MFC libraries are required for this project.

> Error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'atlstr.h': No such file or directory

You can see here the configuration for the C++ project that fails:

[image]

Anybody facing the same issue or knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Well apparently on Thursday the updated 'windows-latest' to 'windows-2022'.

So we were building locally with windows-2019 but the server was windows-2022.

To fix it you just need to update your pipeline yaml:

```
pool:
   vmImage: 'windows-latest'
```

to

```
pool:
   vmImage: 'windows-2019'
```